# Develop Flutter web app on Windows Subsystems for Linux

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, wsl-2

I'm trying to develop web app with flutter on WSL2. However I could not get it work with chrome.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale C.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /home/rayl/development/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (4 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /home/rayl/development/android/sdk
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/rayl/development/android/sdk
    ✗ No valid Android SDK platforms found in /home/rayl/development/android/sdk/platforms. Directory was empty.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /mnt/c/Program\ Files\/Google\/Chrome\/Application/chrome.exe)
    ! /mnt/c/Program\ Files\/Google\/Chrome\/Application/chrome.exe is not executable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

if i run /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe on cmdline. It will open chrome on windows side. but flutter doctor say its not executable.

Comment: Why not simply use the windows tool chain? Or if you want to develop on linux, perhaps use a linux VM, or perhaps even dual boot linux? I think you're going to run into many issues beyond this one trying to get fully up and running in WSL

Comment: because the backend is developing with wsl

Comment: any answer to this? I've also tried export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" but that didn't work either!

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it works if you do CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrom.exe"